How to control the speed of objects in my simple game
I am making a game like space invaders in c++ using the win32 api. I am a beginner.
When I increase my games FPS, game objects move faster across the screen. I want objects to move the same speed across the screen no matter what the FPS is.
I use the <chrono> and <tread> library to determine how many times the main game loops per second and use sleep_for() to add a delay to meet the desired FPS:
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(targetFrameTime - elapsedTime));

I move objects in the main loop like this:
if (userInput.get_right_key_down()) {
     rect_x = rect_x + 5;
}

I would rather not use thread if possible. I don't really understand it and don't know if I need it.

One way to handle this issue using win32 API is to use timers.

How game engines commonly handle this is using "delta time" which is the time between this and previous frame. It can be calculated dynamically or, if the frame rate is constant, 1 / frames per second. Multiply the movement amount by delta time and the object will move at a constant speed regardless of frame rate.

Read Fix Your Timestep!

If your timestep (i.e. targetFrameTime - elapsedTime) is dependent to your FPS, then you have the explanation. Using a fixed timestep will lead to a constant sleep no matter what the FPS are :) But if you want to avoid time drifting (due to the cumulation of processing times), you better need to use sleep_until() instead to sleep_for().

I think the best way is to fix the start time, perform sleep_for for a while, and then perform the movement using the speed factor.
const auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
...
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

Move objects in the main loop like this:
const auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
const std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = end - start;
double dt = elapsed.count();

...

if (userInput.get_right_key_down()) {
     rect_x = (int) ((double) rect_x + 5.0 * dt); // 5.0 - is the speed factor px/sec
     // but the best way is to use rect_x as a field with type of double.
     // and convert (trunc) it to the integer only on the render step
     // rect_x = rect_x + 5.0 * dt;
}

